# HBase tables disappear

Tags: hadoop, hbase

In a psuedo distribute hadoop installation ( hbase, yarn, hdfs ), at one point all HBase's tables disappeared, how can i fix them?

In hbase shell: "list" returns 0 row(s)

Creating a table among those dissapeared named transactions:

```
Api Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableExistsException: transactions
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ForeignExceptionUtil.toIOException(ForeignExceptionUtil.java:45)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin$ProcedureFuture.convertResult(HBaseAdmin.java:4352)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin$ProcedureFuture.waitProcedureResult(HBaseAdmin.java:4310)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin$ProcedureFuture.get(HBaseAdmin.java:4244)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTable(HBaseAdmin.java:649)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTable(HBaseAdmin.java:579)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler.createTable(ThriftServerRunner.java:1192)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.HbaseHandlerMetricsProxy.invoke(HbaseHandlerMetricsProxy.java:67)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.createTable(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Processor$createTable.getResult(Hbase.java:4018)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.generated.Hbase$Processor$createTable.getResult(Hbase.java:4002)
at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.TBoundedThreadPoolServer$ClientConnnection.run(TBoundedThreadPoolServer.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableExistsException): transactions
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.CreateTableProcedure.prepareCreate(CreateTableProcedure.java:300)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.CreateTableProcedure.executeFromState(CreateTableProcedure.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.CreateTableProcedure.executeFromState(CreateTableProcedure.java:58)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.StateMachineProcedure.execute(StateMachineProcedure.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.Procedure.doExecute(Procedure.java:427)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.execProcedure(ProcedureExecutor.java:999)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.execLoop(ProcedureExecutor.java:803)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.execLoop(ProcedureExecutor.java:756)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.access$200(ProcedureExecutor.java:75)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor$1.run(ProcedureExecutor.java:441)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look like problem with the zookeeper.
table is not present in the hbase but actually zookeeper keep all the table information i.e. metadata about table.

So you have run zookeeper cli and remove the /hbase directory from the zookeeper by using this command

> rmr  /hbase

and restart the hbase again it will resolve the problem.